# Error 401 (Unauthorized) in React js in axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am working on a notes website to clear my concepts of the react js. And now when i comes to
user login in react js I am facing a problem.
Actually when i enters the correct username and password then i doesn't get any error in console but as i enter wrong  i face error

**this contians django-rest-framework as backend**

My problem is this that how can i handle it in  console i don't want this error in console is this possible
[image]

Here i am sharing code

```
import reduxStore from "../store";
import axios from "axios";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import {
    LOGIN_PAGE_ACTION_ERROR,
    USER_REFRESH_TOKEN,
    USER_STATUS_ACTION,
} from "../actions/index";

import dayjs from "dayjs";
import { ChevronDoubleRightIcon } from "@heroicons/react/solid";

const baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";

const { dispatch } = reduxStore;

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
});
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
        console.log("object");
        let AuthTokens = localStorage.getItem("AuthTokens")
            ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("AuthTokens"))
            : null;
        if (AuthTokens) {
            const user = jwt_decode(AuthTokens.access);
            const isExpired = dayjs.unix(user.exp).diff(dayjs()) < 1;
            if (!isExpired) {
                config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${AuthTokens.access}`;
                dispatch(USER_STATUS_ACTION(true));
                return config;
            }
            if (isExpired) {
                const response = await axios
                    .post(`${baseURL}/api/token/refresh/`, {
                        refresh: AuthTokens.refresh,
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        dispatch(USER_STATUS_ACTION(false));
                    });
                localStorage.setItem(
                    "AuthTokens",
                    JSON.stringify(response.data)
                );
                dispatch(USER_STATUS_ACTION(true));
                config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${response.data.access}`;
                return config;
            }
        } else {
            dispatch(USER_STATUS_ACTION(false));
        }
        return config;
    },
    function (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    async function (error) {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
            dispatch(LOGIN_PAGE_ACTION_ERROR(error.response.data));
            return error;
        }
        return error;
    }
);
export default axiosInstance;
```

Image from network tab
[image]

Comment: Did you checked that is user has is_active True in database ?

Comment: yes it is true 
But i want to remove this error from console there is no problem with user login if password and username is correct

Comment: but as i provide wrong username or password i get this error now i simply just want remove this error from console i

Comment: Its depend on what is returned from Django API. you can modify that from backend Check your backend code and see if any such conditions.

Comment: Any idea how can i do that
is not possible by  error handling in the frontend

Comment: Do you have backend on github or share what you are referring ? any links ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240775/discussion-between-akash-senta-and-jashandeep-singh).

Comment: You can't do anything about the console logging failed network requests

Comment: Phil do you mean this i have to go for backend change

Comment: https://github.com/jashandeep1659/note-app-django link of backend code